# Image Stitching Based on known Camera Trajectory(RT/ x,y,z and yaw,pitch,roll)

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-stitching

Most of the existing methods for image stitching are based on extract feature from two images, estimate homography matrix and apply wrap transformation. sometimes feature extraction fails or takes time.
I would like to know is there anyway i can stitch the images based on camera path(trajectory)

**56532860911 -0.000502442 0.000134181 -0.0002846 -0.00120646 0.000166193 -0.000169914 0.999999**

**56532890214 -0.00132118 0.000190727 -0.000186955 -0.00274511 -0.000374426 0.000237332 0.999996**

**56532926966 -0.00116131 -0.00185036 -0.000309418 -0.00293733 -0.00137476 0.000914687 0.999994**

**56532959939 -0.00121259 -0.00316659 -0.000751318 -0.0014782 -0.00168121 0.00142819 0.999996**

**56532993423 -0.0012071 -0.0038421 -0.00111284 -0.000266419 -0.00139644 0.00173635 0.999997**

This is my camera pose, 56532890214 this denote timestamp, other values are Translation and rotation of each frames.